# why sass doesn't return the value of a global variable which I had Modified it inside a function?

Tags: css, sass

I was practicing with sass `@function` and I realized when my variable is global scope the function doesn't apply changes to this variable and just return its initial value but when I declare this variable as function scope, changes get applies on this variable without any problem and function returns the expected value, so I was wondering why this is happening in the first situation?

code:

```
//first situation


$s:8;
@function lome($a...){

@each $i in $a{
$s:$s+$i;
}
@return $s;
}

@debug lome(1,2,3);

//expected output:14;
//output:8;
```

```
//second situation

@function lome($a...){
$s:8;
@each $i in $a{
$s:$s+$i;
}
@return $s;
}

@debug lome(1,2,3);

//expected output:14;
//result:14;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer: It's a matter of scope.

```
@function lome($a...){
    @each $i in $a{
        $s:$s+$i;
    }
    
    @return $s;
}
```

Variables declared in blocks (like the `@each`) are usually local, and can only be accessed within the block they were declared.

What's tricky is that *local variables* can be declared with the same name as a *global variable*. You're creating a new local variable in the `@each` block but you're returning the global variable.

Quick test that would give you the proper result and that won't update the global variable:

```
@function lome($a...){
    $x: $s;
    @each $i in $a{
        $x:$x+$i;
    }
    
    @return $x;
}
```

If you really want to update the global variable each time you use the function, you can use the flag `!global`:

```
@function lome($a...){
    @each $i in $a{
        $s:$s+$i !global;
    }
    
    @return $s;
}
```

More information on the [sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables/#scope).

Comment: tnx, now i understand why it works in JS but not in SASS, thats because of the variables behaviour, by the way I can't upvote you cause I don't have enough points to do that but thanks.